# AJAX как получить данные из БД по клику на ссылке в div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Я уже замучался. Кучу ссылок наоткрывал, везде по разному делают, но примерно одинаково, а в итоге у меня всё равно ничего не работает.
На странице есть два блока. В одном ссылка, другой пустой. Нужно по нажатию на ссылку получить из одной ячейки базы данных текст и поместить его в пустой див.
Как я написал - перепробовал уже кучу способов, сейчас напишу то, что на данный момент наделал-переделал.
Файл dbauth.php
Ну тут понятно - просто соединяемся с базой данных

**Файл index.php:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="news">
        <div id="newsID">1</div> //этот блок скрыт, его делал для data: {"newsID:",newsID}; тоже не помогло ничерта с get-ами всякими.
        <div class="more"><a href="#" id="moren">Показать всю новость</a></div>//тут пробовал делать по onclick="opennews()"; в ajax.js убирал moren.click(function() - все равно ничего.
    </div>
</div>    
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**Файл ajax.js (естественно подключен в index.php в хедере):**

```
function opennews() {    
var nID = $("#newsID").val();

$('#moren').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"testnewsshow.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(responce){ 
            $('#bottom').html(responce); //в этот див нужно вывести "новость"
        }
    }
})
}
```

**Файл testnewsshow.php:**

```
<?php
include "dbauth.php"; 
$query = "select * from site.news where id='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
{
print $row['news_full']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, где я косячу? Изучаю потихоньку технологию, основные принципы понятны, но на практике не работает что-то нифига.

Comment: @DizzWebS,  дайте Ваш код, как Вы сделали. А может у Вас не подключена библиотека JQuery?

Comment: @DizzWebS, я задам вам немного не скромный вопрос... Не сочтите за оскорбление, но у вас один элемент на странице с `id = moren`? Если таких несколько, то немедленно исправляйте на `class = moren`

Comment: за оскорбление не сочел:) Я ведь учусь и это логично что есть возможность где-то что-то не туда вставить или вставить лишнего, так что хорошо что проверяем. Но нет, такой элемент у меня один.

Comment: Значится так... пришел на работу, поменял имя переменной в которую результат возвращается,поменял в хедере ссылки на библиотеки ajax вместо 'http://...' сделал "http://..." и в общем-то всё вроде. И всё заработало. Интересно, что это было?) Теперь буду дальше с параметрами пробовать типа GET или POST. Всем спасибо. Код на данный момент такой: http://jsfiddle.net/fQNbs/1/

Comment: при клике в js надо написать 
$('#moren').click(function(){
return false;
        $.ajax({....

Comment: @DizzWebS http://jsfiddle.net/fQNbs/3/

Comment: ни то ни другое не помогло. При return false; не появляется решетка, но и не работает ajax, а с preventDefault и ajax не работает и решетка появляется.

Comment: @DizzWebS, невероятные вещи у вас происходят почему-то... а `return false` надо прописывать в конце функции, а не в начале. Это даже логически понятно =). И уберите из `href` решётку.

Comment: всё, сделал:) Всем огромное спасибо:) поставил return false; после закрывающей скобочки от $.ajax({...}); и всё работает как надо:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас функция `opennews()` служит для того, чтобы добавить event на элемент '#moren'

Так вот, эта функция где-нибудь запускается?

Правильно-то будет вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // либо $(function() {
    $('#moren').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"testnewsshow.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(responce){ 
                $('#bottom').html(responce); //в этот див нужно вывести "новость"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @DizzWebS Кстати, откройте просто файл: testnewsshow.php выводит что-нибудь?

Comment: да, я проверял конечно его на работоспособность - выводит нужную запись из таблицы.

Comment: немного пальцем в небо, но попробуйте исправить предложенный вам вариант примерно вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/m2FbZ/

Comment: Еще один момент - вот этот #moren у меня написан _только_ в ссылке и в js-файле. В css он нигде не определен. Просто во всяких статьях в инете я так понял его тупо так подставляют. И скорее всего я не прав, что так думаю, да?

Comment: jQuery получает объекты с помощью функции $, в которую мы передаем CSS-селектор. Т.е. CSS файл тут не причем.

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей, не помогло. Что-то я совсем не так похоже делаю где-то. Если не везде.

Comment: @DizzWebS дак ёкарный бабай! У вас же наипростейшая ошибка допущена! Вы у функции $.ajax не закрыли круглую скобку! Быстро отладчик в руки и только с отладчиком работать.

Answer (score 2):

$.get уже не тот?

`$.get('testnewsshow.php', function(data) {
 alert(data);
});`

Comment: и вы круглую скобку не закрыли, ай ай ай.

Comment: @lampa, просто с телефона. Ошибся :)

Comment: @DizzWebS, вместо Вашего $.ajax. Путь обновил.

Comment: а все равно не работает. По F12 в Network (в chrome) ничего не происходит. Собственно как и на странице.

Comment: @DizzWebS, если уж опять не работает, то можно попробывать прописать путь так: /testnewsshow.php

Comment: бл*... под вечер мозги мои совсем отказывают. Конечно там путь еще через папку одну до файла. Сейчас и так попробую.

Comment: @DizzWebS, тогда пропишите полный путь. С http:// и т.д. Так мозгу проще Вашему будет :))

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли сделать так

```
  <div id="top">
    <div id="news">
      <div class="more">
        <a href="#" id="moren" onclick="LoadNews('id_новости');return false;">Показать всю новость</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
 <div id="bottom"></div>

function LoadNews('id')
{
    $('#bottom').load('testnewsshow.php?id='+id);
}

<?php
include "dbauth.php";
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = "select * from site.news where id="+$id;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
{
   print $row['news_full'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Может и проще, просто нужно было сделать открытие новости в другом диве без перезагрузки страницы. Я знаю только такой ajax в примере как выше писал. Да и если загуглить, то в основном такие примеры, поэтому и делал так. Я так понимаю, в вашем случае ajax работает через jquery? Читал про некоторые функции работы с ajax через него, но решил пока попробовать просто через непосредственно сам ajax. Хотя Ваш пример красив, забрал в копилку знаний:)

Comment: Да, это jQuery, есть еще много способов как сделать жизнь проще, вот советую почитать http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/