# Передать параметры адресной строки скрипту с помощью AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, get

Это снова я. И AJAX/jQuery. В общем читаю ссылки в инете и понять некоторые вещи не могу. А именно - как мне сделать так, что вот допустим открыт сайт mysite.ru На сайте есть ссылка. Она уже сформирована и ведет на mysite.ru/news.php?p=1 Что нужно мне - чтобы без перезагрузки страницы параметр который в p (который "1") передался с помощью ajax php-скрипту (news.php) и там я уже бы обработал дальше всё. То есть если что, то я бы мог передать 2, если бы написал в строке адреса ?p=2 и т.д.
Как мне каким-нибудь GET-ом это дёрнуть, и чтобы в строке адреса все эти ссылки писались? Я знаю, что в ajax есть параметр data. Но не понимаю как он работает. Пока на ночь сам,  к сожалению, ещё не пробовал "на себе" что называется, но просто даже пока и понять не могу. В угадайку тоже не очень хочется играть.

Comment: Если вы про основы подобные: http://javascript.ru/blog/gordon-freeman/Primery-raboty-s-AJAX-Otpravka-GET-POST-HEAD-zaprosov-cherez-AJAX-javascript или http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=753608 или даже такие http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_GET то из них про строку адреса не понятно ровным счетом нифига.

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165971#166819), все просто, а в ссылку можно просто добавить id новости

```
<a href="#" id="moren" onclick="LoadNews('id_новости');return false;">Показать всю новость</a>
```

так же есть в html5 способ изменить url,  [вот статья](http://web.izjum.com/url-changing-without-page-reloading)
или
[вот еще интересная статья на хабре о навигации как в твиттере](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/45330/)

З.Ы. Как-то сам делал такое, в итоге получил кучу багов, в конце концов выпилил такую навигацию и сделал обычную, уменьшив вес страниц от кучи ненужных элементов, как показала практика, если на сайте нет плеера или повторяющихся страниц как в твиттере, то такая навигация не к чему, проще занятся отладкой страниц, уменьшая их вес.

Comment: Вот примеров много похожих таких. А id новости добавить в ссылку - Вы имеете ввиду вместо "#"? Про работу с адресной строкой уже успел почитать, потом из тех читалок и вылилась эта тема) Просто тут больше интересует вопрос про пагинатор на ajax (у меня вывод по три новости) и строку адреса. Просто фактически мой сайт - одна страница, напичканая всякими скриптами. Смотрится не нагружено, но хотелось бы всё же красивую реализацию тех же новостей для быстрого доступа по ссылке или странице к ним (где по три). Правда думал, что должно оно было проще реализовываться немного:) Попробую по всякому:)

Comment: погулял ещё по инету и видимо всё просто через history делается. Пока правда тоже не совсем понимаю ещё, каким образом)) с hash что-то не очень возиться хочется, хотя, похоже, придется как-то и это затронуть, чтобы для ослика допиливать сайт.

Comment: Чтобы с осликом работало, надо и хэш навигацию иметь, а остальное таки да можно сделать через history.

Comment: Точно) Когда писал, забыл про хэш:)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал. Сразу оговорюсь, что код ТОЛЬКО подставляет URL и подгружает в нужный див инфу из БД, т.е. если перейти по этому URL, вставив его в строку адреса, не произойдет ничего. Плюс нет никаких проверок "от дурака" и плюс ещё не работает кнопка "назад", и пока не сделал "убирание" из строки адреса, собственно, нужной части адреса. Чето ещё там не работает, но функционал, который был нужен лично мне на данный момент, я сделал. Вот код:

P.S. В ослике даже 9 не работает(!)
**index.php**

```
<div id="left_side"><a href="/?p=1" onclick="getpage(event, this); return false">TEST!!!</a></div>
```

**ajax.php**

```
function getpage(event, param) { //функция, записывающая значение p из адреса mysite.ru/?p=1,2,3 и т.д.
var url=param.href;
var urlarr=new Array();
urlarr = url.split('=');
var idx=urlarr[1];
openpage(idx);
event.preventDefault();
};

function openpage(idx) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
    url:"/engine/news.php",
    data: {"idx":idx},
    cache: false,
    success: function(test){ 
        $('#right_side').html(test);
        history.pushState(null,null, "?p="+idx);
    }
})
return false;
};
```

Ну и **news.php**

```
<?php
include "dbauth.php"; 
$idx = intval($_GET['idx']);
$query = "select * from site.news where id='$idx'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['news_full']."<br>";
echo '<a href="#" id="testc">CLOSE AND BACK</a>' //ЭТА ССЫЛКА будет убирать инфу из дива и отсекать тот добавленый адрес в адресной строке.
?>
```